# Scalar photon states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, gauge-theory

I don't really understand what a scalar photon physically is.

I know that in the Coulomb gauge the normal mode expansion of potential $A^{\mu}$ is given by the two transverse polarization, which should be the ONLY physical photons.

In the picture I attached, it is defined an arbitrary physical state through the use of the auxiliary scalar field B.
** edit** $u_{k}= [\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3 2 \omega _{k}}]^{- \frac{1}{2}} \exp{(-ikx)}$

From this definition, scalar photon 1-particle states are physical states just as the transverse one. Maybe I'm just getting confused between definitions, but how could it be? How should I interpret this result?

[image]